# set not getting called

Tags: c#, wpf

In my C# WPF app,  I have the following:

```
    ObservableCollection<SpecialtyFees> _SpecialtyFeeEGG;
    public ObservableCollection<SpecialtyFees> SpecialtyFeeEGG
    {
        get { return _SpecialtyFeeEGG; }
        set
        {
            if (_SpecialtyFeeEGG == value)
                return;

            _SpecialtyFeeEGG = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SpecialtyFeeEGG");
        }
    }
```

When the following line is executed, the SET method gets called, as I expect:

```
        SpecialtyFeeEGG = new ObservableCollection<SpecialtyFees>();
```

However, later on in the code, when the specialtyFee is added to SpecialtyFeeEGG, it is NOT called and I expected it to be called.  What am I missing?

```
        foreach (var item in Specialties)
        {
            SpecialtyFees specialtyFee = new SpecialtyFees();
            specialtyFee.SpecialtyCode = item.SpecialtyCode;
            specialtyFee.CurrentTotal = 0;
            specialtyFee.BidTotal = 0;
            specialtyFee.BidDifference = 0;
            if (specialtyFee.SpecialtyCode.Length == 3)
            {
                SpecialtyFeeEGG.Add(specialtyFee);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `.Add` does not change the acutal object. U need to check `Collection_Changed`-Event for that ! **As an example:** `SpecialtyFeeEGG` could be `readonly` while you could still add items to the collection.

Comment: I believe that you can raise the propertychanged event at the end of your foreach loop after adding all of the items.  As others have observed you aren't actually changing the list, so your set function won't raise it.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of using `ObservableCollection` is as follows:

```
private ObservableCollection<SpecialtyFees> _SpecialtyFeeEGG 
   = new ObservableCollection<SpecialtyFees>();

public ObservableCollection<SpecialtyFees> SpecialtyFeeEGG
{
    get { return _SpecialtyFeeEGG; }
}
```

When using binding in WPF, you need to notify each time a change is made to the binding source. Or otherwise (such as this case) the value always refers to the one specified in constructor or field initializer (`new ObservableCollection<SpecialtyFees>()`). And since you don't need to change to source, the observable collection will take care of the add/remove/changes made to the collection.

Set method is not required in this case neither `RaisePropertyChanged`. However only if you **have to** change the source, then it will be work as you expected to handle the change of the source of the collection.

Answer (score 1):

You only edit the object, not the pointer/reference to that certain object.
It's the same as saying that you have List x.
If you set `x = new List();` You actually make a new list.
When adding something to this list, the reference address of x doesn't change.
While the contents of x does.

Answer (score 0):

The `ObservableCollection<SpecialityFees>` object isn't actually changing, you are merely adding to it's items, therefore it will not fire the `set` method on the object itself.

You will need to use the `SpecialityFeeEGG_CollectionChanged` method to capture the addition to the collection.